# "What would I not exact from you...?"

Tags: meaning-in-context, negation, literature, particles

The meaning of the phrase in bold is incomprehensible to me. Could someone please explain or  paraphrase the sentence for me?

> CAESAR. Vengeance! Vengeance!! **Oh, if I could stoop to vengeance, what would I not exact from you as the price of this murdered man's blood?**
>
> Source: G.B. Shaw, "Caesar and Cleopatra".

- I am concerned about the general idea of the sentence. What if we omit the particle "not" from that sentence? Would the meaning of the sentence change?

> ... what would I exact from you as the price of this murdered man's blood?

- What role does the negation play here?

Comment: It doesn't include "no".

Comment: I can't see a *no* in the sentence. Do you mean *not*?

Comment: Sorry. Yes, I do.

Comment: You can ask for clarification by leaving a comment under users' answers. You now have enough rep to do that. Please do not "change" answers with your uncalled-for edits. If you have any queries about how to do things on EL&U, you can post a request on meta http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that the first clause 'Oh if I could stoop to vengeance' indicates that *vengeance* is not a worthy thing for him to indulge in, it is [**beneath him**](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/beneath%20one's%20dignity).
 The second part is a **[Rhetorical Question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question)** used to indicate that the murdered man's blood is beyond price.

 As to whether there is a contradiction, I would say there isn't: although he *seems* to say that the murdered man's blood is priceless, he means that there is no price that 'others' should not pay, rather than him. 
 However, I wouldn't not argue much with anyone over the interpretation, not knowing the rest of the work!

Comment: @User170800 (I’ve rejected your edit because I don’t think that is the proper way to discuss the answer.)
“what would I not do?” compared to  “what would I do?”      An answer to the first would identify the set of things he *would not* do, an answer to the second the set of things he *would* do. In both cases you learn what the limits are on his willingness to act, but the answers would be completely different.

Answer (score 3):

Theodotus points out to Caesar that Lucius Septimius' murder of Pompey has provided Caesar vengeance against his enemy while preserving Caesar's reputation for clemency.

Theodotus assumes that Caesar is motivated by a desire for revenge, and that Caesar's clemency is merely a political pose.

But Shaw's Caesar is genuinely merciful and in fact detests vengeance. He makes this clear in the line you quote:

> If I could **stoop** to vengeance

means "If I were the sort of person you imagine me to be, a person who demeans himself and makes himself less human by pursuing vengeance"—if he were that sort of person

> what would I not exact from you as the price of this murdered man's blood?

This is, as others point out, a rhetorical question, implying the answer "I would take your life as 'vengeance' for your murder of this man".

A few lines later Caesar also observes that the crimes he himself committed under the color of political expediency were even more detestable:

> Vengeance at least is human. No, I say: those severed right hands, and the brave Vercingetorix basely strangled in a vault beneath the Capitol, were [*with shuddering satire*] a wise severity, a necessary protection to the commonwealth, a duty of statesmanship—follies and fictions ten times bloodier than honest vengeance! What a fool was I then! To think that men's lives should be at the mercy of such fools! [*Humbly*] Lucius Septimius, pardon me: why should the slayer of Vercingetorix rebuke the slayer of Pompey?

This repudiation of vengeance and the 'blood price' is a running theme in what in my dissertation I called Shaw's 'Christian trilogy'—this play, *Androcles and the Lion* and *St. Joan*—because it is for Shaw intimately involved in his rejection of conventional Christian theology and the doctrine of substitutionary atonement.

Comment: As I recall, Shaw's view was that sending criminals to prison or the gallows was merely answering crime with crime. He regarded crime as an aberration, not even much of a temptation to the mass of humanity, and thus not requiring a penal system to keep it in check. He thought the very few incorrigible criminals should be dispassionately killed as a sanitary measure, with no mystique of justice about it, while those who were corrigible should be corrected.

Comment: @BrianDonovan Yes. What he objected to most vehemently was the self-deceiving idealist mindset which demanded that judicial/political murders (and lesser crimes) be represented as virtuous adherence to some "higher" principle.

Comment: @user170800 DO NOT post responses in the body of an Answer using the *edit* button: that overwrites the Answer. Post a request for clarification as a Comment using the *add a comment* link below.

Comment: @user170800 See Brian Donovan's comment above, and my response; and examine Caesar's reply in that context and the context of Rufio's "parable of the lion": *Rufio: had you set yourself in the seat of the judge, and with hateful ceremonies and appeals to the gods handed that woman over to some hired executioner to be slain before the people in the name of justice, never again would I have touched your hand without a shudder. But this was natural slaying: I feel no horror at it.*

Answer (score 2):

"what would I not exact from you" could be rephrased as "I cannot think of anything that i would not exact from you", "exact" in this context being the verb form, which means to take something from someone.  The original question is of course **rhetorical**.

So you could further rephrase "What would I not exact from you" as ***"I cannot think of anything that I would not take from you".***  I suspect that things he has already "thought of" would involve injury and death: he's saying that he would stop at nothing to get revenge, if he could "stoop to vengeance".

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "what would I not" means "what limits would I place on myself". In other words, is there anything I would not do to exact revenge?

But here the question is rhetorical. What he is really saying is, I would place no limits on myself. In other words, there is nothing I would not do to exact revenge.

Answer (score 1):

You asked specifically for a paraphrase, so I'll give you that - the other answers ably cover the use of "not" and the subsequent rhetorical device.

> Oh, if I could stoop to vengeance, what would I not exact from you as the price of this murdered man's blood?

Overall means:

> If I could bring myself to avenging this act, I would stop at nothing, and there are no limits on what I would do to you to try to balance this murdered man's death